# Converting basic r barplot to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've currently got a barplot  that has a few basic parameters. However, I'm looking to try and convert this into ggplot. The extra parameters don't matter too much; the main problem that I'm having is that I'm trying to plot the sum of various columns, but I'm unable to transpose it correctly as `t(data)` doesn't seem to work. Here's what I've got so far:

```
## Subset of indicators
indicators <- clean_data[c(8, 12, 14:23)]

## Get sum of columns
indicator_sums <- colSums(indicators, na.rm = TRUE)

### Transpose for ggplot
(empty)


## Make bar plot
barplot(indicator_sums, ylim=range(pretty(c(0, indicator_sums))), cex.axis=0.75,cex.lab=0.8, cex.names=0.7, col='magenta', las=2, ylab = 'Offences Recorded Using Indicator')
```

Comment: See [this example](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/218-basic-barplots-with-ggplot2.html), try taking ``data <- data.frame(
  name= 1:length(indicator_sums),  
  value=indicator_sums
)`` and build from there

Comment: I can't thank you enough; this solved my problem immediately!

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

dummy <- data.frame(
  A = c(1:20),
  B = rnorm(20, 10, 4),
  C = runif(20, 19,30),
  D = sample(c(10:40),20, replace = T)
)
barplot(colSums(dummy))
```

[image]

```
dummy %>%
  colSums %>%
  melt %>%
  rownames_to_column %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = rowname, y = value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]